# How to require() all files in a directory and send arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, autoload, autoloader

## How do I require all the files in a directory?

I need to require all files in a directory and send a variable along with it.
Like: `require(file)(app)`. I've tried [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir) but I can't figure out how to send the `(app)` part with it.

Comment: Please show or describe more about what you're trying to accomplish.  Usually doing a `require()` assigns the module to a known variable name so it can be referenced in other code.  The require-dir module source code is here https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir/blob/master/index.js to you could just grab it and modify it to suit your needs too.  Or you could just make a list of module names and a loop to cycle through the array loading them.  It's unclear to me which part of this problem you don't know how to do yourself.

Comment: I don't need a variable name, I just want to `require()` a bunch of files so I can put things such as `routes` in a different file. The `routes` need the `app` variable to run, hence I do `require(./routes.js)(app);`. But I don't want to require every file manually, I want it to happen automatically.

Comment: Please put that additional info into your question (use the edit link to add it) so your question describes better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are NOT supposed to put your solution into your question.  If the answer you ended up with is not close to any of the answers you were provided, then you can post your own ANSWER to your question with your solution in it.  Questions here should remain questions.  Don't put answers in your questions.

Comment: I did that in case anyone else ends up googling this question.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to put a finished solution into an answer to your own question if you think it would be useful to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep using `require-dir`, try this:

```
var dir = requireDir('./path/to/dir');
for (var key in dir) {
  dir[key](app);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use `fs`:

```
require('fs').readdirSync('./yourdir').forEach(function(file) {
  require('./yourdir/' + file)(app);
});
```